# How to use ? operator in Option's .map() method?

Tags: rust

REPL: https://www.rustexplorer.com/b/8roccj

I'm new to Rust and I just discovered this strange error:

```
the `?` operator can only be used in a closure that returns `Result` or `Option` (or another type that implements `FromResidual`)
```

I would like to use it like:

```rust
let player = Player::new(
    &input.id.unwrap_or_default(),
    input.team.map(|team| Team::new(&team.id)?),
);
```

I expect Rust to throw `Result`'s `Err` if `Team::new()` errors.

Why not?

All the code:

```rust
struct Team {
    id: String,
}

impl Team {
    fn new(id: &str) -> Result<Self, &'static str> {
        Ok(Self { id: id.to_string() })
    }
}

struct PlayerCreate {
    id: Option<String>,
    team: Option<Team>,
}

struct Player {
    id: String,
    team: Option<Team>,
}

impl Player {
    fn new(id: &str, team: Option<Team>) -> Self {
        Self {
            id: id.to_string(),
            team,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let input = PlayerCreate {
        id: Some("fake".to_string()),
        team: None,
    };

    let player = Player::new(
        &input.id.unwrap_or_default(),
        input.team.map(|team| Team::new(&team.id)?),
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't make sense in multiple ways:

1. `Option::map` is a conversion from a T to a U, it's not designed with failure in mind (although nothing precludes U being some sort of failure type since they're normal types after all)
2. `?` doesn't make sense in terminal position, it just creates additional complexity: `?` is equivalent<sup>1</sup> to

   ```
   match <thing> {
       Ok(v) => v,
       Err(e) => return Err(e.into())
   }
   ```

   So it "shortcuts" the error and unwraps the success, but since it shortcuts the error to an error *you still need to return a result from the function*.

   So you need `return Ok(foo?)`, which doesn't really make sense unless you need the conversion bit, and it'd probably clearer to `Result::map_err` the conversion instead
3. why are you... creating a new team from a team you already have? Why not just use the existing team?
4. it's not entirely clear what's supposed to happen if team creation fails, is that supposed to surface an error or just set the new player's team to `None`?

WRT 4, if a team creation failure just sets the new player's team to `None`, you can simply use `.ok()` to convert the `Result` to an `Option` (failure becomes `None`), and `and_then` to allow faillible transformation:

```rust
input.team.and_then(|team| Team::new(&team.id).ok())
```

On the other hand if a team creation failure should *error*, then you just use map without ?:

```rust
input.team.map(|team| Team::new(&team.id))
```

This results in a `Option<Result<Team, &str>>`, the outer `Option` from the original team maybe not existing, and the inner `Result` from the team creation possibly failing. Now you need to flip the two so you can surface an error, and [`Option::transpose`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.transpose) will do that for you:

```rust
input.team.map(|team| Team::new(&team.id)).transpose()
```

yields a `Result<Option<Team>, &str>`, then you can handle the outer `Result` however you want e.g. `?`, `unwrap`, ...

---

1: in this specific case, `?` is a lot more flexible than that and notably works with Option as well, but it only does `Result -> Result` and `Option -> Option` translation, it can't cross the streams

Answer (score 0):

Rust doesn't have any mechanism to "throw" errors. The `?` syntax is simply a shorthand for returning early if a result indicates an error.

So what you're writing here:

```
input.team.map(|team| Team::new(&team.id)?)
```

is equivalent to

```
input.team.map(|team|
return match Team::new(&team.id) {
  Err(err) => Err(err)
  Ok(res) => Ok(res)
})
```

which you'll note is the exact same thing as if you hadn't written the `?` there at all. And since your closure must return `Team` (`result.map(...)` must return `Option<Team>` in your example), this doesn't typecheck.

Aside from that, your `map` call is also just never going to work because you're trying to create a `Team` from a `Team` that's not there, and if a team *is* there you just create an identical one. Maybe you just meant

```
let player = Player::new(
        &input.id.unwrap_or_default(),
        input.team,
    );
```

Comment: The `?` will unwrap the value so the match doesn't include the `Ok()` for the `Ok` branch, also the early `return` is inside the `Err` branch only, not before the match. See Masklinns answer for a correct desugaring.